# Server Side Rendering (SSR) in Meteor with react-router to load once at startup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, react-router, server-side-rendering

In front end libraries like ReactJS we can not manually type URL's because the router is not loaded initially to look for that specific route. This is solved by a plugin [meteor-react-router-ssr](https://github.com/thereactivestack/meteor-react-router-ssr), but due to this routes matching the whole page refreshes - It does not feel like Meteor App anymore.

So the question is: **Can we use SSR on startup only (so that if someone enters a URL can be redirected to the correct route and SEO) and then shift to react-router without SSR ?**

Answer (score 0):

> Can we use SSR on startup only (so that if someone enters a URL can be redirected to the correct route and SEO) and then shift to react-router without SSR?

That should be happening already. SSR is only used for the initial render but React is then loaded on the client and the react state is 'picked up' by it.

Do you have react-router set to use the browser history API?

```
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router'

...    

  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    ...
  </Router>
```

Comment: <Router history={browserHistory}>
   <Route path="/" component={ App }>
      <IndexRoute component={ Home } />
    </Route>
    <Route path="*" component="NotFound404" />
  </Router>
Yes! I did, these are my routes